# Google reCAPTCHA for MVC 4 and 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, recaptcha

I saw the Google reCaptcha for MVC 4 and 5 nuget package (http://recaptchamvc.apphb.com) recommended several times on SO.  But when I try to use it on my MVC 4 site, I get this:

Compiler Error Message: CS1705: Assembly 'reCAPTCHA.MVC, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Does it not actually support MVC 4?  Or is there something I need to configure to get it to do so?

Comment: You can see more at here
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842517/version-conflict-with-system-web-mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842517/version-conflict-with-system-web-mvc)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: yes, i switched to react and node.js

Answer (score 0):

The .net 4.0 library is linked to MVC4, the .net 4.5 library is linked to MVC5.